# Constructor behaviour c++

Tags: c++, constructor

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{

    public:
        int x;
};

int main()

{

    A a = A();
    cout<<a.x<<endl;

}
```

For this code I am getting the output as 0 but when i create the object as A a; and then print a.x, I get garbage value. Why is this so?

Comment: I am trying to understand the behaviour of default constructor. Can anyone tell whether or not default constructor initializes member values to their default values?